# Karate UI: Entering input using variable values

Tags: karate

KarateUI question
I'm trying to enter values in a text field using a variable.  Example:

```
* def foo = bar
* waitFor("input[aria-label='Search Input']").input('<foo>' + Key.ENTER)
```

This results in value  being entered in the Search Input field.

I have been using the '<[something]>' successfully on a number of other places, not sure why it's not working in the above example.

I have tried a number of other approaches following the documentation without much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate "variables" can be mixed into plain JavaScript. So try this:

```
* def foo = 'bar'
* waitFor("input[aria-label='Search Input']").input(foo + Key.ENTER)
```

That's right, no angle-brackets required.

Also see: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

If still stuck, follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter.  That was embarrassingly simple.